# PyQt5 coding Problam

Tags: python-3.x

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
import sys

class Mywindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):

super(Mywindow, self).__init__()

self.out = ""

self.con = {'L': '1', 'O': '2', 'V': '3', 'E': '4'}

self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)

self.lab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

self.lab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

self.line1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)

self.initUI()

self.show()

def initUI(self):

self.btn1.setText("Enter")

self.btn1.move(200, 150)

self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.action)

self.lab1.setText("input :")

self.lab1.setStyleSheet('font-size:20px ;color:blue')

self.lab1.move(100, 150)

self.line1.text()

self.line1.move(80, 200)

def action(self):

for i in self.line1.text():

self.out += self.con[i.upper()]

self.lab2.setText(self.out)

self.lab2.setStyleSheet('font-size:30px ; color :red')

self.lab2.move(200, 250)

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = Mywindow()

win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have 2 problems in this code:

1. If I enter the letter in line edit out is coming. But when I clear the line edit and enter again previous output are still there and out put coming together... I wanted method is when i clear the line edit i need out put also clear.
2. If I enter out of letter LOVE application will closed. I don't want like that.

This code I make TkInter it's working nicely, but Pyqt5 has showing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reset `self.out` value at the begging of each action:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
import sys

class Mywindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Mywindow, self).__init__()
      self.out = ""
      self.con = {'L': '1', 'O': '2', 'V': '3', 'E': '4'}
      self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
      self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
      self.lab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
      self.lab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
      self.line1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
      self.initUI()

   def initUI(self):
      self.btn1.setText("Enter")
      self.btn1.move(200, 150)
      self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.action)
      self.lab1.setText("input :")
      self.lab1.setStyleSheet('font-size:20px ;color:blue')
      self.lab1.move(100, 150)
      self.line1.text()
      self.line1.move(80, 200)

   def action(self):
      #clear output
      self.out = ''

      for i in self.line1.text():
         self.out += self.con[i.upper()]
         self.lab2.setText(self.out)
         self.lab2.setStyleSheet('font-size:30px ; color :red')
         self.lab2.move(200, 250)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = Mywindow()
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can also use `keyPressEvent` to clear or set output dynamically.